# Routing a page using Material select, and routerLink, Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

So currently I'm routing to a page to get a list of documents from a policy. I'm also bringing in all of the policies so you can navigate through the select form and re-route you to it with the policy number passed. Is there a way to get on selection of the option to navigate using the new url?

```html
<mat-form-field name="selectPolicy">
    <mat-select placeholder="Change Policy">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let policy of policies" 
            [routerLink]="['../', policy.policyNbr]">{{policy.policyTypeDesc}}
            #{{policy.policyNbr}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

As of right now, this changes my url, but does submit to the new page once changed.

Comment: What do you mean it changes your url, but does not submit to the new page? The url in the address bar changes but you don't see the change reflected on the page?

Comment: You need to create an eventListener that fires on change and uses the router.navigate logic

Comment: @MitchMcCutchen This is correct, I see the dynamic change of the URL but I am not taken to the new URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
//assuming you have a route set up to take the value as a param
navigateTo(value){
  console.log(value);
  this.router.navigate(['../',value]);

}
```

```html
 <mat-form-field name="selectPolicy">
        <mat-select placeholder="Change Policy" (selectionChange)="navigateTo($event.value)">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let policy of policies" [value]="policy.policyNbr">
            #{{policy.policyNbr}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: so the function would live in the component.ts, but would it be in the class, or the constructor?

Comment: This ended up working the code I had was in the wrong place, so it would not reload the state.

Answer (score 0):

In the class, can be after ngOnInit if you have one